# Symfony2 JS update Form area

Tags: javascript, symfony

I made a form, and have Entity
i want to make,that depend on dropdown choise show different form style for one entity

for example in JS

```
var firsttype=<div class="form-row form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        {{ form_label(form.line1, "Passport Line 1", {"label_attr": {"class": "control-label"} }) }}
    </div>            
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 controls">
        {{ form_errors(form.line1) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.line1) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row form-group ">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        {{ form_label(form.line2, "Passport Line 2", {"label_attr": {"class": "control-label"} }) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 controls">
        {{ form_errors(form.line2) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.line2) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row form-group ">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        {{ form_label(form.nameOnDocument, "Name on Document", {"label_attr": {"class": "control-label"} }) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 controls">
        {{ form_errors(form.nameOnDocument) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.nameOnDocument, {"attr" : { "class": "form-control"} }) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        {{ form_label(form.expireDate, "Expiry Date", {"label_attr": {"class": "control-label"} }) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 controls">
        {{ form_errors(form.expireDate) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.expireDate, {"attr" : { "class": "form-control" } }) }}
    </div>              
</div>
```

such different styles and change different style to form ,depend on dropdownlist

```
$('.form_type').html(firsttype);
```

Because if choise 1, you need to feel all information, if choise 2, just add simple info